# Unable to upgrade pip properly and given "/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip" on command

Tags: python, django, pip

I'm making a website on django and I receive the warning below about pip. I have updated it twice, once outside docker and the other within it. I still receive this warning. How do I go about properly updating it?

WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 20.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: Can you share the exact command you ran to update pip?

Comment: and also the command you used to install libraries

Comment: I tried pip install --upgrade pip as an administrator on my computer. I then within my docker server "docker-compose exec web python manage.py upgrade pip". Both successfully ran but the error still shows.